# ActiveAdmin belongs_to routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I've created new app with activeadmin gem. I wanted create two nested resources with 'belongs_to' method but I get error.

First resource

```
ActiveAdmin.register Project do
end
```

Second resource

```
ActiveAdmin.register Ticket do
    controller do
        belongs_to :project
    end
end
```

Error when I tried open neped resource

**No route matches [GET] "/admin/projects/1/tickets"**

What I do not right?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need to do here is move `belongs_to :project` out of the controller block and into the register block (up a level, basically). If that doesn't work, we may need to see the model definitions.

Comment: Thanks for help. I moved this code into register block but I get other error `ActiveAdmin::Resource::BelongsTo::TargetNotFound`

Comment: When I go to `/admin/projects/1/tickets` I see this error `No route matches [GET] "/admin/projects/1/tickets"`

Comment: Can you post the projects and tickets models (just the part where the relationship is defined, the business logic I don't need)? According to this [test on line 29](https://github.com/startae/activepress/blob/master/spec/unit/belongs_to_spec.rb) this may be a problem with how the relationship is defined.

Comment: First model

`class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :tickets
end`

and second


`class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
`

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
ActiveAdmin.register Ticket do
controller do
    belongs_to :project
end
```

with

```
ActiveAdmin.register Ticket do
    belongs_to :project
```

I was facing a very similar error and this thread helped me a lot! My model definition was 
incomplete and I needed to add a Has_many association.

Answer (score 0):

First, move the `belongs_to` declaration out of the controller block. Then, the child resource requires that you specify the `:parent_class', so for you it should look like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Ticket do
  belongs_to :project, :parent_class => Project
end
```